# How to create table of contents for an Excel file generated by C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, ms-office

I have to implement an Excel export in an application where the exported Excel file should contain something like a table of contents on the second sheet.

This sheet should refer to the other sheets with page numbers - so if the customer prints out the Excel file, they can use this table of contents.

Given some assumptions on the page size, margins, etc., does anyone have an idea on what kind of library should I use to fulfill this requirement?

Or the only possible way of doing this is calculating the page numbers with VBA macros?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, it seems that I can use Aspose.Cells to calculate the page numbers for the table of contents:

```
var workbook = new Workbook("Erstfassung.xls");
var pagesSoFar = 0;

foreach (var worksheet in workbook.Worksheets)
{
    var pageCount = worksheet.GetPrintingPageBreaks(new ImageOrPrintOptions()).Length;
    Console.WriteLine($"{worksheet.Name} - ({pageCount} long), starts from {pagesSoFar}");
    pagesSoFar += pageCount;
}
```